# Does each IDE needs its own Python?

Tags: python, ide

I have PyCharm, Visual Studio Code and Jupyter Lab installed on my PC, and the PC has Python 3.11 installed?

Would someone please educate me on this topic?

If I want run 3 Python programs simultaneously (each program uses its own IDE). Would each IDE run faster if each IDE has its own Python program? Right now all IDEs are using the same Python 3.11 and things are working fine. Just for my own knowledge, I am just curious of this topic. Thank you in advance for educating me!

Comment: No, did you have a proposed mechanism in mind for why that would be the case?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to use Python to download a bunch of data. However, to  save time, I wanted to use 3 different IDEs to run 3 different programs concurrently. I was curious if running 3 different Python IDEs concurrently would be lower or faster than if one were to run them consecutively. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to discriminate the two following concepts: **program** and **process**.

### Program

A program is a list of instructions. It's generally written on a file.
It can be a binary text but also an ASCII text.
**A program does nothing**. It is basically a static text.

### Process

A process is the execution of a program by your operating system.
A process has a dedicated memory and execution time. Its role is to "play" your code, instruction by instruction.

---

In your example, *python.exe* is a program.

When you execute it, your operating system will create a dedicated process.

So, when you run several IDEs, you simply run several process of your same program.
Thus, there is absolutely no loss in terms of performance.

Comment: Hi, I am so grateful for your taking the time to help me understand this point.